# How does the Facebook App on iPhone access the SMS data from iMessages? What are the details?

Tags: databases, facebook, iphone

(This is not a repeat question to "How is Facebook accessing my iPhone texts in order to recommend friends?", linked below. I wish to know the internal details of how downloading the Facebook app on a smartphone allows Facebook to see SMS data, particularly from iMessages. I am asking for the technical details here.)

Assuming the answers to this question are correct: 
[How is Facebook accessing my iPhone texts in order to recommend friends?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96772/how-is-facebook-accessing-my-iphone-texts-in-order-to-recommend-friends)

How does the Facebook app access SMS data? Somehow, downloading the Facebook app grants Facebook access to SMS data via iMessages (if you use an iPhone). I would like to understand how this works.

What other data is Facebook able to access on smartphones as soon as you download the FB app?

Comment: While you may get an answer here, this seems more of a straight iOS question. https://apple.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place for it.